# Getting ConnectionException: Connection refused on a file transfer app

Tags: java, sockets, server

So, I am creating a simple file transfer app. When I run it I get a Connection refused error. Now, there isn't a problem with the Firewall, because when I tried to run a sample code from the book I am following, it ran perfectly. The Server starts without error.

Server code:

```
public class Server
{
final static int TRANSFER_PORT = 1215;
final static int FILEINFO_PORT = 1216;
static int filesize;
static String filename;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    ServerSocket fileInfoSocket = new ServerSocket(FILEINFO_PORT);
    try
    {
        System.out.println("Server Started");
        Socket s = fileInfoSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("Connected");
        InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);
        filesize = dis.readInt();
        filename = dis.readUTF();
        s.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println("File info received.");

    ServerSocket fileTransferSocket = new ServerSocket(TRANSFER_PORT);
    byte[] fileByteArray = new byte[filesize];
    try
    {
        Socket s = fileTransferSocket.accept();
        InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        bis.read(fileByteArray, 0, fileByteArray.length);
        s.close();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        bos.write(fileByteArray);
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println("Transfer complete!");
}
```

Client code:

```
public class Client
{
final static int FILEINFO_PORT = 1216;
final static int TRANSFER_PORT = 1215;
final static String SERVER_ADDR = "localhost";
static int filesize;
static String filename;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    if(args.length != 1)
    {
        System.out.println("Usage: Client filename");
        return;
    }

    File file = new File(args[0]);
    if(!file.isFile())
    {
        System.out.println("File not found!");
        return;
    }
    filesize = (int) file.length();
    filename = file.getName();

    Socket fileInfoSocket = new Socket(SERVER_ADDR, FILEINFO_PORT);
    try
    {
        OutputStream os = fileInfoSocket.getOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
        dos.writeInt(filesize);
        dos.writeUTF(filename);
        dos.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
    }

    Socket fileTransferSocket = new Socket(SERVER_ADDR, TRANSFER_PORT);
    try
    {
        OutputStream os = fileTransferSocket.getOutputStream();
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(os);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[filesize];
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        bis.read(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
        bos.write(byteArray);
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Error on Terminal when Client is run:

```
pratyush@SuperComputer:~/JP/NetworkFileTransfer/Server$ java Client "a.png"
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at     java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at     java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at     java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at Client.main(Client.java:54)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannot understand exacly on which row the exception is thrown if on fileTransferSocket, maybe the fileTransferSocket has not time to open. Try to put a sleep in the client:

```
  Thread.sleep(100);
```

Before:

```
  Socket fileTransferSocket = new Socket(SERVER_ADDR, TRANSFER_PORT);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. But please explain, what exactly changed when I put the client to sleep(at the end of the first try block). Because earlier, the Server never even got to the println() statement when it was supposed to print "Connected" after the accept() method returned

Comment: The program are running at the same time, so the server will arrive to the Socket fileTransferSocket = new Socket(SERVER_ADDR, TRANSFER_PORT); at the same time has the client trys to open it...Sadly it does not open in time so the client can never connect